# R version of SUMIFS or AVERAGEIFS?

Tags: r

I'm trying to conditionally find the average of column 1/column2 based on T/F values in col3 and col 4. I have 1000 rows of data so I was wondering in R had a way to all of them.

```
kg  ha  condition 1  condition 2 
2   1   True         True
3   0.5 True         False 
4   1   False        True 
5   0.5 False        False
```

I'm VERY new to R so I'd appreciate if you could use the data set I provided so I can follow along more easily. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  If it is False, then would that be NA

Comment: Is this a variation of your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961059/how-can-i-calculate-a-conditional-sum-with-true-false-information Did none of those answers help?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to replace the values the first two columns based on the logical values in 'condition1, '2', and then get the `rowMeans`

```
rowMeans(replace(df1[1:2], df1[3:4] == "False", NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1.5 3.0 1.0 NaN
```

Instead of doing the `==`, it can also be converted to logical with `as.logical`

If it is the sums, replace the `rowMeans` with `rowSums`

---

If the 'condition1', 'condition2' are grouping columns, then

```
aggregate(.~ condition1 + condition2, df1, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

In `R`, boolean values are `TRUE/FALSE` and not `True/False`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(kg = 2:5, ha = c(1, 0.5, 1, 0.5), condition1 = c("True", 
"True", "False", "False"), condition2 = c("True", "False", "True", 
"False")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: The `tidyverse` and `dplyr` answers are very popular these days, which is the only reason I am holding off on upvoting this answer; I tend to prefer being shown the base-R ways of doing things, although I don't get the sense that's what "the community" is looking for.  But this is the "best" answer, including mine.

Answer (score 1):

dplyr package is perfect for this task. I'll assume your data is saved as My_DF

```
library(dplyr)
My_DF %>%
group_by(condition 1, condition 2) %>%
summarize( avg_kg = mean(kg, na.rm = TRUE),
           avg_ha = mean(ha, na.rm = TRUE) )
```

This code take your dataframe, and generates means for variable kg and ha for each combination of condition 1 and condition 2.

The %>% is called a pipe, it passes the result of the previous line as an input to the next line.

This site contains some helpful one page guides to dplyr and basic R:
https://rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/

Comment: Beat me to it.  I'll add mine so they have some context for building `My_DF`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to acquaint yourself with the `tidyverse` package, or more specifically `dplyr`, as Andre mentions.  I'll provide slightly more context around making his example `My_DF`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  col_one = sample(1:10, 25, replace = TRUE)
)
df$col_two <- {df$col_one > 5}

df %>% 
  group_by(col_two) %>% 
  summarise(
    totals = sum(col_one))
  )
```

which will give you something like

```
> glimpse(df)
Observations: 25
Variables: 2
$ col_one <int> 3, 7, 10, 1, 7, 7, 10, 6, 3, 8, 7, 3, 4, 8, 1, 2, 2, 6, 5, 6, 3, …
$ col_two <lgl> FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TR…
> df %>% 
+   group_by(col_two) %>% 
+   summarise(
+     totals = sum(col_one))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  col_two totals
  <lgl>    <int>
1 FALSE       35
2 TRUE        97
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to `sum()` or average (`mean()`) `kg` and `ha` when conditions are true, this can be done very simply.

**Data:** (note I removed the spaces from `condition 1` and `condition 2`.

```
data <- data.frame(kg = 2:5,
                   ha = c(1, 0.5, 1, 0.5),
                   condition1 = c(T, T, F, F),
                   condition2 = c(T, F, T, F))
```

**Conditional Sum**

The sum of `kg` when both `condition1` and `condition2` are `TRUE` is,

```
sum(data$kg[data$condition1 & data$condition2])
```

So then this expands to,

```
sum(data$kg[data$condition1 & data$condition2])
sum(data$ha[data$condition1 & data$condition2])
mean(data$kg[data$condition1 & data$condition2])
mean(data$ha[data$condition1 & data$condition2])
```

Or you can do this on both at once,

```
colSums(data[data$condition1 & data$condition2, c("kg", "ha")])
colMeans(data[data$condition1 & data$condition2, c("kg", "ha")])
```